# Индикатор доступа ресурса

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно сделать индикатор доступности ресурса? Т.е есть ресурс необходимо проверит доступе ли он или нет постоянно пинговать его не вариант на данный момент так:

```
label.Content = new Ping().Send("172.30.216.27").RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms";
```

Есть идея сделать индикатор зелёный доступе красный нет, опрос каждые 20 секунд. Но не знаю как это сделать прошу помочь.

**UPD** Люди помогите остановить этот поток

```
new Thread(() =>
                {
                    var ipAddr = _label.Text;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddr))
                    {
                        ls1:
                        try
                        {
                            var pingSender = new Ping();
                            var reply = pingSender.Send(ipAddr);

                            if (reply != null && reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                            {
                                Invoke((Action) (() =>
                                {
                                    _label.BackColor = Color.Green;

                                }));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Invoke((Action) (() =>
                                {
                                    _label.BackColor = Color.Red;

                                }));
                            }

                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            this.Invoke((Action) (() =>
                            {
                                _label.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            }));

                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(20000);
                        goto ls1;
                    }

                }).Start();
```

Comment: При разрыве связи запускай таймер и давай красный свет, пингуй в нем, при удачном варианте стопори таймер и давай зеленый свет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно еще так сделать:

```
        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {

            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("172.30.216.27");
            PingReply reply;

        ls1:
            try
            {
                reply = pingSender.Send(address);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
                    {
                        label.Background = Brushes.Green; 
                        label.Content = "Ping "+reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms"; 
                    }));

                }
                else
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
                    {
                       label.Background = Brushes.Red; 
                       label.Content = "No answer"; 
                    }));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
                 { 
                   label.Background = Brushes.Red; 
                   label.Content = "No answer"; 
                 }));
            }


            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            goto ls1;
        }).Start();
```

Просто вставить этот код в начале программы и раз в 20 секунд он будет отправлять пинг на ресурс. В примере он меняет цвет фона label1. Соответственно можно менять цвет элемента.

**UPD**. Внес правки и добавил обработчик потому что при обрыве связи выскакивала ошибка.

Comment: В принципе подходит если сделать так  if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    label.Background = Brushes.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    label.Background = Brushes.Red;
                } вот только проблема ошибка Дополнительные сведения: Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток. Ругается на label.Background = Brushes.Green;

Comment: Это потому что нужно `Invoke`. Можно в условии написать так:    `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                     label.Background = Brushes.Green; 
                })); `

Comment: Всё большое спасибо помогло c маленькой доработкой можете в ответ внести все изменения: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { label.Background = Brushes.Red; }));

Comment: можно ещё использовать **do { } while (true)** вместо **goto**

Comment: Люди помогите остановить это чудо, так как приходится убивать процесс.

Answer (score 1):

Кратенько о [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
//Создаём
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer m_PingTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer() { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20) };
//Создаем делегат тика
m_PingTimer.Tick += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Тут делаем Вашу магию с пингами
  label.Content = new Ping().Send("172.30.216.27").RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms";
  if (всё зашибись)
    m_PingTimer.Stop();
};
if (всё плохо)
  m_PingTimer.Start();
```